# AWS RDS : Why Suddenly Number Of Connections Increased?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have EC2 server for private use. It only runs CRON continuously to access RDS instance.

for past few days, it runs normally. but suddenly I got a lot of notification and it says it failed to connect RDS instance.

when I checked RDS console, the number of connections is increased :

[image]

what makes this connection suddenly increased? it's private use. no other people accessing this server besides me. I only use 10 EC2 instance to access 1 RDS. so I'm not reaching maximum connections, right? then where these connections comes from?

[image]

Comment: Using the master user account for the RDS instance, run the query `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`.  This will identify the IP addresses of the machines that are connecting.  The fact that you are only running 10 EC2 instances means nothing.  Each instance can potentially create many thousands of connections.  As it stands, the answer to your question is most likely "because your code is not doing what you believe it is doing."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you might want to post that as an answer, since it is excellent advice. That way the question doesn't look unanswered when it really isn't.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : thanks for your comment, bro. I tried `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; ` as you suggested and yes now I can see what process currently running. but how can I know what process happened in the past? because currently the connection is dropping after I upgraded my instance. is it possible to check process list that happened few hours ago?

Comment: The process list is only available in real-time.  RDS/MariaDB does, however, support the [Audit Plugin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.Options.AuditPlugin.html) which can be configured to audit `CONNECT` events.  If you have this enabled, already, then you can review the audit log.  If not, consider enabling it, now, so you'll have it for next time.

Comment: @SaintRobson Did you got any solution for this? after I upgraded my RDS i am also seeing sudden spike in session count.